# Deployment security in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to find how and the best practices for securing access to Microsoft Team Services.

We are looking at auto deployment from Team Services, but we have a concern about it being in the cloud.

Our machines are hosted with a third party and we need to ensure that the deployments only come from our Team Services, is this possible and what are the best practices to ensure the best security possible.

Comment: Do you realise that it is very broad question and very hard to answer? Cloud is just somebody else's machine. And you already have machines hosted with a third party. You can have build agents hosted on machines under your control.

Comment: Not clear about your scenario, how do you deploy app? Do you want to deploy application to azure? Azure web app or azure VM? What's scenario that the deployments come from other Team Services?

Comment: Okay keeping things simple, where do I find the best practice for security when using Team Service?

Comment: Which scenario has the security issue? Others don't have the permission to access your machine, how do they deploy project from their VSTS to your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft do a lot of things to keep your Team Service project safe and secure, refer to this link for details: [Visual Studio Team Services Data Protection Overview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/team-services-security-whitepaper).

And for your question, you can [deploy your own build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows) which you can have full control and easy to configure your machines to only accept the deployment from that build agent.